# Lucene find index in multivalued field?

Tags: solr, lucene, solarium

I have a multivalued field of names and I have to find the index of the matching value in the list.

```
DOC example:

profile_id: 1
names: [ "My name", "something", "My second name", "My nickname"]
```

query:

```
profile_id:1 AND names:"My secon name"~
```

Expected result:

```
my doc, and the index of the matched, 2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try this query? Because multivalued field handled the same way. May be you need clarify question what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: expetcted result means what I need, instead the response is simply the doc, without knowing which of names's index is matched

Comment: MultiFieldQueryParser - allows you specify as many names as you need.

Comment: Also this link(I never tried) http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/search-through-all-fields-td548608.html talkd about field *all*

Comment: That 'index' thing is very ambiguous since the term "Index" is primarily used in Lucene for inverted-index. I believe you are looking for 'position' of matched term, right?

Answer (score 0):

[SpanTermQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanTermQuery.html) matches documents just like TermQuery, but it also keeps track of position of the same terms that appear within the same document.

```
Spans positionInfoForAllMatchingDocs = spanQuery.getSpans(..arguments..);
int position = -1;
while(positionInfoForAllMatchingDocs.next()){
      position = positionInfoForAllMatchingDocs.start() // Returns the start position of the current match.
      System.out.println("Found match in the document with id: " + positionInfoForAllMatchingDocs.doc() + " at position: " + position); // You obviously want to replace this sysout with something elegant.
}
```

- Make sure that the field, for which you are planning to retrieve the positional information, was indexed with Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS or Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS.